# ControlClick not working with AutoItX3

Tags: automation, autoit

I am currently trying to use AutoItX3 to do some automation.

My script opens up an application and now I want it to click on the certain button within the app. This is my code for the ControlClick (parameters were acquired from the AutoIt v3 Window Info Tool) :

```
Local $sText = WinGetTitle("[ACTIVE]")<br>
ControlClick($sText, "", "[CLASS:WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d; INSTANCE:62]",     "left", 1, 21, 12)
```

Unfortunately, this code does not seem to do anything at all. I replaced it with a regular mouse click with coordinates, but then this script won't work on any computer with a different resolution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using consoleWrites to get the info about what doesn't work. Try to skip the controlId. Just use title and text and then "", ... Did you set the option to for using classes at all?

Comment: How do I use ConsoleWrite to get the error message? The documentation just shows that I have to pass in a data string. Also, how would I get the mouse click to be at a specific location in a window without using the controlID?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to understand what I meant.

```
Example()

Func Example()
    ; Run Notepad
    Run("notepad.exe")

    ; Wait 10 seconds for the Notepad window to appear.
    WinWaitActive("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 10)
    ControlSetText("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", '', 'HELLO WORLD!')
    ; Wait for 2 seconds to display the Notepad window.
    Sleep(2000)
    ControlSend("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", '', '{Right 20}{ENTER}NEW LINE!')
    ; Close the Notepad window using the classname of Notepad.
    WinClose("[CLASS:Notepad]")
    WinWaitActive("Editor", "", 10)
    ControlSend("Editor", "", '', '!n')
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this code helps. It does exactly what it is supposed to (Except the last two actions don't run because the notepad window is already closed by then), but doesn't really help my case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that AutoIt spy tool identifies the button individually?Some times AutoIt info tool identifies a some portion of a application(multiple buttons or multiple tabs)as single object.In that situation you have to use the mouseclick opration and after that use control click function like below

```
mouseclick("",21,21)
Controlclick("","","button1",21,21)
```

this might help you.make sure to capture the x and y coordinates from the Mouse tab of autoIt info tool.

Answer (score -2):

Sometime it could happend on some windows protected with an anti-bot/macro systems such as games, java clients etc...

You could by-pass this using a VM with a third-party desktop controler such as teamviewer/RDP/... You will be able to run your script thru the RDP session.

Please Note: AutoIt is not made to make GameBots :)

Vlu.